# Django: creating a data migration for a model that is deleted in another migration results in error

Tags: django, django-migrations

I have a Django 4.2.2 app with a `Character` model, which I am migrating to a brand new model (and database table) called `Content`. I first created the new model, added the migrations for it, then added a data migration to migrate data from `Character` to `Content`, and then I removed the `Character` model and created a migration for that.

While working on the steps one by one, and running the new migration on every step, it all worked (locally). But when running `./manage.py migrate` on the staging database I get this error:

```
LookupError: App 'characters' doesn't have a 'Character' model.
```

This how how my data migration looks like:

##### content/migrations/0002_auto_20230630_1434.py

```python
from django.db import migrations


def run_data_migration(apps, schema_editor):
    Content = apps.get_model("content", "Content")
    Character = apps.get_model("characters", "Character")

    # Migration logic here


class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    dependencies = [
        ("content", "0001_initial"),
        ("characters", "0009_alter_character_avatar_alter_character_avatar_crop"),
    ]

    operations = [migrations.RunPython(run_data_migration)]
```

Important to know is that `0009_alter_character_avatar_alter_character_avatar_crop` is the migration step *before* the complete removal of the `Character` model. So since I am depending on that step before the removal and I am using `apps.get_model` instead of trying to use the `Character` model directly, I would've thought this just worked?

How do I make sure that the data migration within the `Content` app runs before the migration in the `Character` app that deleted the `Character` model? Like, it works if I would commit the migrations as separate commits, check them out one by one on the server, run the migrations one by one, etc. But of course it needs to run as one single migration step as well.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, found it

```py
class Migration(migrations.Migration):
    # ...

    run_before = [
        ("characters", "0010_delete_character"),
    ]
```

I was under the impression that the `dependencies` also controlled the order, but nope.